# Turtle gives error: AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'onkeyrelease'

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to add 1 every time I release a key:

```
from turtle import *
import turtle
turtle1 = Turtle()
screen = turtle1.getscreen()
goPressed = False
```

imported Turtle...

```
currentWatts=0

def onaclicked():
     global currentWatts
     currentWatts+=1
     print (currentWatts)
```

defined my function to be run when the key: 1, is released

```
turtle.onkeyrelease(onaclicked, "1")
```

for some reason `onkeyrelease` isn't there even though I imported Turtle and checked in Python documentation. It SHOULD work, shouldn't it? Did I improperly import? Can you please help me?

The reason I want it to be `onkeyrelease` instead of `onkey`, is because it is for a game. With `onkey`, when you hold your finger on the key, it adds 1 to currentWatts every around 0.25 seconds. You could cheat by placing something on the key so I want it only to add 1 when you release the key.

Comment: @DavyM, the OP's use of `turtle` is not the turtle class but the turtle library and is actually valid given the import statements.  Using `turtle1` instead is simply wrong.  The problem may be use of Python 2 which doesn't include the `onkeyrelease` alias.

Comment: @cdlane Oh okay, thanks. That's why I made it a comment since it looked like an object issue, but since I didn't know enough about `turtle` to even recognize it as a library and not a class file, I knew I could have been completely off base. I'm glad you were able to give a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've several problems with your code: you import turtle two different ways which confuses things; `onkeyrelease()` is really a method of the screen/window, not a turtle; you didn't call `listen()` which allows keystrokes to be processed.  The following should work in Python 3:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, mainloop

def onaclicked():
    global currentWatts
    currentWatts += 1
    print(currentWatts)

currentWatts = 0

screen = Screen()

screen.onkeyrelease(onaclicked, "1")

screen.listen()

mainloop()
```

Make sure to click on the window once before you start typing to make it active.

If you're using Python 2, which I suspect from the error message you got, then replace the Python 3 alias `onkeyrelease` with `onkey`:

> The method Screen.onkeypress() has been added as a complement to
>   Screen.onkey() which in fact binds actions to the keyrelease event.
>   Accordingly the latter has got an alias: Screen.onkeyrelease().

This change should work the same in both versions.  Using `onkeyrelease` instead of `onkey` wasn't going fix your holding a finger on the key issue.

> when you hold your finger on the key, it adds 1 to
>   currentWatts every around 0.25 seconds. You could cheat by placing
>   something on the key so I want it only to add 1 when you release

It appears that automatic key repeats are handled by the operating system and may need to be disabled external to Python, depending on the OS.  Some example links:

- Apple OSX: [Set how quickly a key
  repeats](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18410?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US)
- Ubuntu: [Turn off repeated key
  presses](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-repeat-keys.html)
- X-Windows from Python: [key repeat in
  tkinter](http://computer-programming-forum.com/56-python/8a344bb91fc18a30.htm)

Comment: Ok. Well, when I tried that just now, it said screen had no attribute onkeyrelease. why is this the case? I have the latest version of python @cdlane

Comment: 'screen.onkeypress' isn't working either, same error

Comment: @Cedric, I copied the above code and pasted it into a file -- it runs fine in Python 3 and generates a "no attribute 'onkeyrelease'" error in Python 2 as I said it would.  Invoke your Python with `--version` and tell us what you get.

Comment: thank you @cdlane, I was on python 2.7.10. That is quite weird because the file i have downloaded for python is named python 3.6.1