# How do I remove repeat delay in Python (with turtle) in Repl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm making a game where you can use the arrow keys to move your character. Every time I hold any of the keys, it doesn't repeat until a second later. I want to make it so whenever I hold the right arrow key, it continues to repeat without the one second delay.

I'm using Python Turtle and I tried to find this out for a week and I couldn't find anything to solve this issue.

```
import turtle

p = turtle.Turtle()
p.shape("turtle")
p.speed(0)

screen = turtle.Screen()

def up():
  p.forward(10)
def left():
  p.right(-10)
def right():
  p.right(10)

screen.onkey("Up",up)
screen.onkey("Left",left)
screen.onkey("Right",right)
screen.listen()
```

(still don't have an answer after one month)

Comment: Suggest add define of `p` & `screen` so people could have a minimal workable code quickly to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turtle gives error: AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'onkeyrelease'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345100/turtle-gives-error-attributeerror-turtle-object-has-no-attribute-onkeyrelea)  Specifically the final paragraphs of the accepted answer.

Comment: Whenever I use onkeyrelease, I get this message AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'onkeyrelease', I am using Python (with Turtle) Repl.

Answer (score 0):

I coded a slightly different turtle program by adding a "backward" function and using the 'left()' method on the 'left' function. This code was able to achieve continuous movement by holding down the arrow keys.

```
import turtle

t=turtle.Turtle()
t.penup()
t.speed(0)
LoadWindow=turtle.Screen()
LoadWindow.setup(width=1000, height=1000)

def f():
    t.forward(10)

def l():
    t.left(10)

def r():
    t.right(10)

def b():
    t.forward(-10)

LoadWindow.onkey(f,"Up")
LoadWindow.onkey(l,"Left")
LoadWindow.onkey(r,"Right")
LoadWindow.onkey(b,"Down")



LoadWindow.listen()
LoadWindow.exitonclick()
```

Also, I imported your code into Repl.it and Trinket and it worked fine as well, which could mean there may be an issue with your connection to the website or your computer is running slow for whatever reason.

If the issue continues to persist I'd recommend trying a different python browser program such as:

- https://trinket.io/python
- http://www.skulpt.org/

Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem of removing the repeat delay. I also tried using different python browser programs but they didn't work. I'm trying to make the turtle continue to move when holding down a key. Instead, whenever I hold down a key, it moves once, waits a second, then continues to move. I want to remove the "wait a second".

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue while writing one more version of the famous Pong, and solved it by changing the logic a bit. Instead of just reacting with up / down methods in onkeypress, I changed it to start moving up or down. Accordingly, I stop moving using onkeyrelease, and it works fine without any delays. Here's some sample code:

main.py:

```
playscreen.screen.onkeypress(left_racket.start_going_up, "Up")
playscreen.screen.onkeypress(left_racket.start_going_down, "Down")
playscreen.screen.onkeyrelease(left_racket.stop, "Up")
playscreen.screen.onkeyrelease(left_racket.stop, "Down")

game_on = True
while game_on:
    playscreen.screen.update()
    ball.move()
    left_racket.update()
```

racket.py:

```
def start_going_up(self):
    self.dy = 1

def start_going_down(self):
    self.dy = -1

def stop(self):
    self.dy = 0

def update(self):
    margin_y = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - BORDER
    if self.arr[0].ycor() > margin_y and self.dy > 0:
        return
    if self.arr[-1].ycor() < -margin_y and self.dy < 0:
        return
    for t in self.arr:
        t.goto(t.xcor(), t.ycor() + self.dy)
```

Hope it helps someone.